# Documents spool but don't print over network from Mac to Windows

Tags: windows-xp, printing, osx-mavericks, network-printer, print-spooler

I recently got a new MacBook Air with Mavericks 10.9.2. The printer I'm trying to print to is an HP LaserJet P1005 connected to a Windows XP laptop. When installing the printer, I used the 'Generic Postscript' driver (seeing that it worked for others online). So I open the queue and print the test page. After entering my password, it connects to the printer and leaves the queue. I go over to the XP and look at the queue, and sure enough, it is sitting there. Under status it says Printing, but after a few minutes it disappears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The P1005 is a GDI printer that does not support PostScript. Sending PostScript to a GDI printer will produce absolutely nothing, as you have found out. You need to install the correct driver for your printer on the Mac. HP have OSX10.9 drivers available [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4062&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3435676).